# PhoneGap Build: Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR (missing files)

Tags: phonegap-build, phonegap

When I try to use my app from PhoneGap Build, it seems to be missing images.  When I check in the Chrome web inspector, it's also missing script files.  Here are the errors:

```
cordova.js:314 Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR
    at fileService.js:77
    at fail (FileEntry.js:88)
    at Object.callbackFromNative (cordova.js:295)
    at <anonymous>:1:9
cordova.js:312 Error in Error callbackId: File410316782 : Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR
cordova.js:314 Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR
    at fileService.js:77
    at fail (FileEntry.js:88)
    at Object.callbackFromNative (cordova.js:295)
    at <anonymous>:1:9
.png:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I know I didn't fail to include this file, because it was working before.

Answer (score 0):

Most issues like this, as well as "Upload Error [2]", can be solved in PhoneGap Build by deleting the app and re-uploading.  Don't worry about losing anything, since all of your settings are in your config files.  It seems that PhoneGap has a tendency to inadvertently retain or misplace files.

I tend to just delete my app and re-upload every time I need to run a build, so I don't have to waste time installing and opening the app, only to find out it's missing files.